# Type "ä" and receive "ae" in Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse

Can eclipse (or my ubuntu system) be configured such that typing an umlaut key (ä, ö, ü, ß) on a german keyboard results in the ascii-sequence (ae, oe, ue, ss or Ae, Oe, Ue Ss)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [autokey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/) for global text substitution.

Answer (score -1):

For Java Editing -

1) Preferences > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Java > Java Editor Text Font

2) Edit Select a font which supports a German typeset

Comment: That does not answer my question. I don't want to display the umlauts but change them to ascii-sequences mentioned while I am typing.